# how to restore stdout after using dup2 to capture stdout to file?

Tags: c

edit: using fopen to create the capture file. Then `fileno` to get the fd of the capture file. Then use fd as input to `dup2` to redirect stdout to this capture file.  Anyway, get same results. `fflush` does not flush and save the captured output.

I want to redirect stdout to a file. Capture some output. Then terminate that redirect and resume output to stdout.  How to do this?

`freopen` handled the redirect.  But I read I cannot resume output to stdout. So I am using `dup` and `dup2`.

Problem with `dup2` is once I shutdown the redirect all the output goes to stdout. The output both before and after the redirect.

I have tried to flush the redirect captured output using `fsync`. But that does not work. When I use `gdb` to step through the code nothing is written to the redirected output file until the program actually ends.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
  // open() returns a file descriptor file_desc to a
  // the file "dup.txt" here"

  FILE *fp1 = fopen( "dup.txt", "w");
  int fd = fileno( fp1 ) ;

  if (fd < 0)
  {
    char errtxt[256];
    strcpy( errtxt, strerror(errno)) ;
    printf("Error opening the file. %s\n", errtxt );
  }

  int saved_stdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2( fd, STDOUT_FILENO);

  printf("line 1\n") ;
  fflush(fp1) ;
  printf("line 2\n") ;
  fflush(fp1);
  fclose(fp1) ;

  // revert back to stdout
  dup2(saved_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);
  close( saved_stdout ) ;
  printf("line 3\n");
  printf("line 4\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Very confusing. If I insert a `return 0` after the output of the first two lines, that output shows up in the output file.  But running the code which resumes output to stdout causes all the output lines to appear on the console and there is nothing in the output file.

Comment: You are closing the underlying file descriptors, but you're not flushing the FILE *.

Comment: I thought that is what fsync does.

Comment: `fflush` will do an `fsync`, but it also updates meta data in `stdout`. By directly calling `fsync` instead of `fflush`, that meta data is not getting updated, which is (probably) having an impact.  (I'm speculating)

Comment: In particular, when you call `printf("line1\n")`, most likely nothing is written to the file descriptor at all.  So calling fsync and then close doesn't cause anything to be written, because the data is still sitting in the internal buffer.  When you open a new fd, if you then fflush, the data will go to the new fd.  If you close the fd before you ever flush, then nothing will ever get written.

Comment: Try adding `fflush` after each `printf`.

Comment: fflush is not flushing.   ( at least now I understand the relationship between file pointer and file descriptor. )

Comment: Tangential: including `<fcntl.h>` twice is unnecessary, but AFAICS, you don't need that header at all, nor do you need `<limits.h>`, `<libgen.h>`, `<time.h>` or even `<stdlib.h>`.  Avoid including unnecessary headers, but include all necessary headers.

Comment: You have: `FILE *fp1 = fopen( "dup.txt", "w"); int fd = fileno( fp1 ) ;` — you need to test that the `fopen()` worked before using the file pointer.  You will probably get a crash (segmentation fault) if the file cannot be opened.  IMO, you should never pass a literal string to `fopen()` or `open()` or their relatives — you need the name in a variable so that you can use it in the error message.  I dislike `perror()` because it doesn't make it easy to include all the desirable information in the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

> ```
>   printf("line 1\n") ;
>   fflush(fp1) ;
> ```

you are writing to `stdout`, but flushing an altogether different stream.  That the two are both connected to the same file descriptor is irrelevant -- each stream has its own, separate buffer.  Instead, flush the stream to which you have actually written:

```
  printf("line 1\n");
  fflush(stdout);
```

*etc*.

As a result of that error, yes, the data you write while the redirect is in effect are not flushed to the target file.  You then restore the original `stdout` before the data are flushed at program exit.

With that in mind, observe that you have confused matters by using `fopen()` to open a stream bound to the file when all you ever needed or wanted was the file descriptor.  `open()` would be a better choice here:

```
  int fd = open("dup.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666) ;
```

Now there is no second stream  to complicate the situation.

As a separate matter, note also that this ...

> ```
>     char errtxt[256];
>     strcpy( errtxt, strerror(errno)) ;
>     printf("Error opening the file. %s\n", errtxt );
> ```

... comes pretty close to duplicating the behavior of the standard `perror()` function, except that it writes to `stdout` instead of `stderr` (which is a flaw).